# Pressing Ctrl+C for stopping Xvfb from bash script

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome-terminal

I have written something like this in my bash file

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"sudo apt-get install xvfb; Xvfb :99 -ac; exec bash\""
```

After

```
Xvfb :99 -ac;
```

I have `Xvfb` running on terminal as shown in the picture. I want to stop `Xvfb` and return to my parent terminal after 2 seconds. How can I do this. What code I need to insert before exec command
I want to stop this

[image]

Comment: @ViggoLundén I want to do the operation Ctrl+C using bash

Comment: It"s not clear what your script seeks to accomplish. Certainly the `exec` after the `exit` will never be reached.

Comment: @tripleee I have now edited the question

Answer (score 0):

just like that:

```
gnome-terminal -e "Xvfb :99 -ac"
```